# (Python 3) Can anyone explain that output below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started to learn Python but I'm stuck on string formatting. I was just playing code but I couldn't understand why below behavior occurs.

Can anyone explain it?

Code:

```
nums = [4, 5, 6]
msg = "Numbers: {0} {2} {1} {2}". format(nums[1], nums[2], nums[1])
print(msg)
```

Output:

```
Numbers: 5 5 6 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I clearly understand that string formatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `format`function.
It would take `{number of parameter in format function}` that you define in brackets.

Let's do some preprocessing for msg line:

```
nums = [4, 5, 6]
msg = "Numbers: {0} {2} {1} {2}". format(nums[1], nums[2], nums[1])
```

is equal to

```
   msg = "Numbers: {0} {2} {1} {2}". format(5, 6, 5)
```

because you are taking elements from `nums` list by indexes (0 based index)

And finally `{number}` in format would take it from arguments:

```
msg = "Numbers: 5 5 6 5". format(5, 6, 5)
```

So `{0}` and `{2}` are equals to 5 and 
`{1}` is equal to 6

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with python , but the answer seems very easy to me

```
   nums = [4, 5, 6]
```

this means nums[0]=4 , nums[1]= 5 , nums[2] = 6

now in

```
    msg = "Numbers: {0} {2} {1} {2}". format(nums[1], nums[2], nums[1])
```

which means by order it will give values in 0,1,2

```
   {0} = nums[1] 
   {1} = nums[2] 
   {2} = nums[1]
```

so the final result becomes

```
   {0} = nums[1] = 5
   {2} = nums[1] = 5
   {1} = nums[2] = 6
   {2} = nums[1] = 5
```

so you get result 5565

Answer (score 0):

the `{0}`,`{1}`, and `{2}` refer to the values `nums[1]`, `nums[2]` and `nums[1]` respectively (or 5,6, and 5 respectively). Therefore, when you write:

```
"Numbers: {0} {2} {1} {2}"
```

its really like writing:

```
Numbers: nums[1] nums[1] nums[2] nums[1]
```

or,

```
Numbers: 5 5 6 5
```

the above are all equivalent